# Fire a method when listBox reaches the last item

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

is there any way to determine, that listbox selected item reached the last item?

Each item in my listbox is a link to webpages, and I want to call logout method when the last page in the list is visited.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (listBox.SelectedIndex == (listBox.Items.Count - 1))
{
    //...
}
```

**Edit** according to Thomas' suggestion in the comments:

You could add this code to the listBox' `SelectedIndexChanged` event, to react on every selection change in the `Listbox`:

```
listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (s,e) => 
{
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex == (listBox.Items.Count - 1))
    {
        //...
    }    
};
```

Comment: @sauk, put this code in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler (assuming this is WinForms)

Comment: tried this code in SelectedIndexChanged event and getting this error Error "A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: thank you for the solution, codes are working perfectly, the logout function is fired as the listbox reaches end of items. one hitch is that, it is effecting other listbox, the mechanism of the program is that, listbox1 items are ids, which logs in a website post all the items of listbox2 and when listbox2 reaches end of item it logouts. the problem is, after using this code, listbox1 items (which are ids are skipped), those ids are meant to login, when webbrowser is at login page. thanks anyways.